# Representation of linked list such as in lisp

Tags: data-structures, lisp, cpu-architecture

Could anyone give an overview of how linked lists such as in LISP are represented in memory of the computer? Does the computer make use of cpu registers to hold the pointers the head and rest of the list or is the heap what is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This strongly depends on the particular compiler and language runtime being used. However, in general data structures in Lisp-like languages are heap-allocated cells with pointers to their neighbours. These are then loaded into hardware registers when functions operate on the data.

Consider the linked list type in Haskell:

```
 data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

A given list might be written as:

1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : (5 : []))))

or more concisely:

[1,2,3,4,5]

This is represented as a heap-allocated object of the form:

[image]

where arrows represent pointers; and `(:)` represents a "cons cell", a small structure storing a pointer to the current element, and the tail of the list.

Now, when a function accesses this data structure, it will load pointers to the structure into registers, and start loading data from those pointers. The precise details of which depend on the compilation model and runtime system model. E.g. for GHC Haskell this is given by the [STG Machine](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67083). In addition, lower-end bits in the pointers can be used to indicate the particular constructor being pointed to; its evaluation status (evaluated or unevaluated) and even the value itself if it is small (this is the [pointer tagging optimization](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ptr-tagging.pdf)).

Answer (score 3):

For such philosophical questions about Lisp, one of the most inspiring source is [Anatomy of Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007001115X). Even if it is a bit dated now. Reading it (well, many years ago) was an enlightenment for me, not only about Lisp but about programming in general. Another excellent book about Lisp implementation is [Lisp in Small Pieces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521545668). If you are serious about learning Lisp internals, these two will help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. Stackoverflow is best if you have a real problem.

'LISP' is large family of languages and hundreds of different implementations.

All kinds of ways to implement linked lists have been tried already.

There are books about Lisp implementation and there are lots of small and large open source Lisp implementations to study.

Relevant literature can be found for example here: http://library.readscheme.org/page8.html